# Centre 2 select controls horizontally and vertically within a div

Tags: html, css

I currently have the following. The controls are positioned vertically on top of each other - what is the easiest way of having these controls side-by-side horizontally and both being centered inside the div element?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>center controls</title>
    <!-- <link rel="Stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css" /> -->
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
    #dropDownDiv {
        position: absolute;
        border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        left: 150px;
        top: 15px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 35px;
    }

    select {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dropDownDiv">
        <select id="opt1">
            <option value=1>Option 1</option>
            <option value=2>Option 2</option>
            <option value=3>Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <select id="opt2">
            <option value=1>Option 1</option>
            <option value=2>Option 2</option>
            <option value=3>Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete the `select{display: block;}` part, and target #dropDownDiv the way Dekel said.

`display: block;` essentially means: Put the element in a new line. Just letting you know. It took me 2 years before I learned it ;) It has other functionalities, but you can read about them.

Take a look at this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKVrEG I used flexbox from the link above. grid was giving me some strange results
All you need to do is add these 3 lines to the #dropDownDiv styles

```
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

This should also work for the child elements which size is unknown.

Comment: (upped) thanks alex - I also want them centered vertically  - so horizontally in a line but they need to be down a little in that div - any ideas

Comment: Take a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Considering that `display: grid` is finally supported (http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3Agrid) I would personally go with it

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `select` elements to `inline-block` instead of `block` and the `text-align` of their container to `center`:

```css
select {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 9.5px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#dropDownDiv {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  left: 150px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropDownDiv">
        <select id="opt1">
            <option value=1>Option 1</option>
            <option value=2>Option 2</option>
            <option value=3>Option 3</option>
        </select><select id="opt2">
            <option value=1>Option 1</option>
            <option value=2>Option 2</option>
            <option value=3>Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Or use flexbox on #dropDownDiv

Comment: @alex3wielki why use flexbox when you don't need it?

Comment: Just stating the options.

Comment: @alex3wielki you can also use `float` and `absolute` position :) but I wouldn't use any of them... it doesn't make any sense to do so.

Comment: I just realized `select` is `display: inline-block` by default, so we don't even need to display it as inline-block. I agree that in this case we didn't really need flexbox and the fancy stuff, but it's better to know it and not use it, then the other way around ;)

Comment: @alex3wielki you are correct. I set it to `inline-block` because the original had `block` and I needed to override it.

Comment: @Dekel (upped) I'd like those select controls right bang in the middle of the div - so vertically centered as well

Comment: @whytheq to set the vertical center I added a margin-top of `9.5px`. This number is 35 (container height) -16 (select height) divided by 2.